# How can I abort pending procedures of hbase?

Tags: hbase

I run hbase performance tools, and thousands tables have been created. And our cluster is currently in inconsistent state (We dont know what is the cause but we try found it), at first I try to disable/drop created tables (1700 tables) but nothing done. list_procedure show 492 rows, and It's not possible to abort any of them. Then, I restart hmaster service, but now, I got infinite number of following exceptions:

```
2018-12-09 20:01:30,194 WARN  [MASTER_SERVER_OPERATIONS-master-4:16000-0] master.AssignmentManager: Failed assignment of t53889,00000000000000000007603345,1542715604227.4cc63591941dbe928663
88fbde075cac. to data-22-54,16020,1543392184445, waiting a little before trying on the same region server try=1 of 10
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionAlreadyInTransitionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionAlreadyInTransitionException: Received OPEN for the region:t53889,0000000
0000000000007603345,1542715604227.4cc63591941dbe92866388fbde075cac. , which we are already trying to CLOSE 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.openRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1604)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.AdminProtos$AdminService$2.callBlockingMethod(AdminProtos.java:22239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.sendRegionOpen(ServerManager.java:772)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:2164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager$2.process(AssignmentManager.java:860)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.EventHandler.run(EventHandler.java:129)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can we stop such logs!?

Output of `list_procedures` contains something like this:

```
1530 DisableTableProcedure (table=t2151) FINISHED Fri Dec 07 11:32:45 +0330 2018 Sun Dec 09 20:07:59 +0330 2018
1532 DisableTableProcedure (table=t21514) FINISHED Fri Dec 07 11:42:53 +0330 2018 Sun Dec 09 20:07:27 +0330 2018
1534 DisableTableProcedure (table=t21518) FINISHED Fri Dec 07 11:53:02 +0330 2018 Sun Dec 09 20:07:57 +0330 2018
1535 DeleteTableProcedure (table=t13946) FINISHED Fri Dec 07 12:02:59 +0330 2018 Sun Dec 09 20:07:27 +0330 2018
```

I don't know if I remove /hbase/MasterProcWALs from hdfs will problem or not.

Any help will be appreciated.

With best regards.